# C++ Recursive Variadic Templates with extendes Base case

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

i want to use recursive variadic  templates with a base case with more than 2 types. The following example does not compile. What could be the problem?

My expectation was that f<int, int>(5) would call a case like:

> [with T = int; Arg = int; Args = {int}]

but that seems to be no option for the compiler (g++ c++17) ;)

```
template<class T, typename Arg, typename... Args>
void f(T a) {
}

template<class T, typename Arg>
void f (T a) {
}


int main() {
    f<int, int>(5);
    return 0;
}
```

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:11:18: error: call of overloaded 'f<int, int>(int)' is ambiguous

   11 |     f<int, int>(5);

      |                  ^

<source>:2:6: note: candidate: 'void f(T) [with T = int; Arg = int; Args = {}]'

    2 | void f(T a) {

      |      ^

<source>:6:6: note: candidate: 'void f(T) [with T = int; Arg = int]'

    6 | void f (T a) {

      |      ^

Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Why do you expect this `[with T = int; Arg = int; Args = {int}]` exactly? You've specified 2 `int` parameters for `f`. Are you expecting `Args` to be deduced from `5`?

Comment: Yes i thought that would work. Because in this example it works (Yes i know a bit different, but i thought it would be analog): ```template<typename X>
int square(X num) {
    return num * num;
}

int main() {
    return square(5);
}```

Comment: The difference there is you are not specifying the template arguments, so deduction has to take place.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both cases and use a [*constexpr if statement*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) in the function template:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T, typename Arg, typename... Args>
void f(T a) {
    std::cout << sizeof...(Args) << '\n';

    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) > 0) {
        f<T, Args...>(a);
    }
}

int main() {
    f<int, int>(5);

    std::cout << "---\n";

    f<int, int, double, float, int>(5);
}
```

Output:

```
0
---
3
2
1
0
```